# Handling "Web service operation foo with parameters {xyz={}} cannot be found." in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldbox

I have created a SOAP web service in ColdFusion, which takes a numeric parameter.

```
<cfcomponent>       
    <cffunction name="foo" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="xyz" type="numeric" required="true">
            <cfset returnMessage = "" />
            <!--- some logic --->
            <cfif some condition>
                <cfset returnMessage = "some error message" />
            <cfelse>
                <cfset returnMessage = "some success message" />  
            </cfif> 
        <cfreturn returnMessage />  
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

It works fine as long as we call the web service with numeric parameters.
When we pass parameters with other data types such as string or blank, ColdFusion gives following error:

```
Web service operation foo with parameters {xyz={dd}} cannot be found.
```

I wanted to know, is there a way to handle the issue and return a custom error message instead of ColdFusion error. 
For eg. if the web service is called with string parameter, I should be able to return a custom message like "`String parameters are not allowed!`".
**Update**:
I am using ColdBox framework. Is there anything in ColdBox that may help.

Comment: Have you tried using Application.cfc's onError function? Ben Nadal has a nice blog post on it [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1567-handling-remote-api-errors-with-application-cfc-s-onerror-event-method.htm)

Comment: I have but in `onError` method I cannot check the parameters passed to web service. I should be able to validate the parameters and return the desired messages based on validation.

Comment: If you can't determine the error based on the one thrown by CF, you could change your argument type to string, and then validate that it is numeric in the function. If it's not numeric, then throw a custom error that the onError function could interpret and relay the desired message to the user.

Comment: I agree with @beloitdavisja last comment. However, be aware that it still will not catch all errors such as if more than one parameter is passed to your web service. That again will throw the "service with parameters ... cannot be found" error. You will probably want both error handling techniques.

Comment: I agree with @beloitdavisja. In fact I have kept it as my last option. But changing the data type of the argument will also get reflected in WSDL. The WSDL generated will give false description about the web service and will attract more invalid inputs.

Comment: Then I suspect your only recourse is to use the onError method as was originally suggested. Have you dumped the entire error structure to see what is available to you when an error occurs?  Also dump the CGI scope and see what is there. You will need some extra logic in the onError method and remember that it will also fire for regular page request errors, not just web service call errors. That Ben Nadel post shows how to distinguish between the two.

Comment: I suggest that you do nothing.  In most, if not all programming languages, if you fail to pass the correct arguments to a native function, an error is thrown with which the developer must cope.  The fact that this is a user defined function should not let developers off the hook.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree with you. But based on requirement, I have decided to use beloitdavisja suggestion. This way we have more control over the response messages based on inputs.